# Opening a network file using CreateFile fails with FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createfile

So I'm trying to simulate a distant file opening, which is pointing back to my computer, however i keep failing with error 3 (FILE_NOT_FOUND). I went through the following [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regarding network usage, but it didn't work either.

```
hFile1 = ::CreateFile(LR"(\\172.17.12.172\C$\Develop\Code\File.txt)", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile1)
{
    LOG_ERROR(L"Failed opening file with: " << GetLastError());
    break;
}
```

1. The FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE flags are for the GetFileInformationByHandle which is used later on, i compare file paths.
2. I tried opening `\\172.17.12.172\C$\Develop\Code\File.txt` using notepad, it worked.

172.17.12.172 is my local ip address.

Comment: Why the () in the path?

Comment: I used the R prefix, so i wouldn't need to use escape chars

Comment: Escape chars have nothing to do with it. Parenthesis just don´t belong there.

Comment: @deviant the delimiters are `"(` and `)"`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your file name is fine. That the error code is `FILE_NOT_FOUND` rather than some other error means that the directory is found, but no file within that directory can be located.

You should be able to open a file with a path of that form using `CreateFile`. If you really can open the file with that path using Notepad, then you will be able to do the same using `CreateFile`, so long as you pass the same file name.

So the most plausible explanation is that you simply made a typographical error. I see no reason to look beyond the obvious conclusion suggested by `FILE_NOT_FOUND`. There is no file of that name.